# How to apply margin on angular material select component

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
 <mat-select>
     <mat-option  value="1">Option 1</mat-option>
     <mat-option  value="2">Option 2</mat-option>
     <mat-option  value="3">Option 3</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

CSS code in my CSS file

```
.cdk-overlay-container .cdk-overlay-pane{
        margin-top: 7%;
     }
```

How to apply margin-top on mat-option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below style in style.scss file

```
.mat-option{  
  margin-top :7px;
}
```